# In Elder Sign, if you need to draw from a deck and there are no cards left, do you lose the opportunity?

Tags: elder-sign

There don't seem to be a large number of spell cards, and Dexter Drake can accumulate cards very fast.  If the spell deck (or any other deck for that matter) runs out, do players simply lose the privilege of gaining a card in cases that award them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no cards left, then you do not gain anything.  Ideally, you should be making use of these cards as often as possible to ensure that future gains do not get wasted due to not having cards available.

(Remember that all discarded cards go immediately to the bottom of their appropriate decks -- so you may want to spend spells freely in encounters that have spells at stake -- they'd then be at the bottom of the deck, and available as part of your reward.)

Exact quote from page 13 of the rules:

> After all dice on a Spell card are removed, the player returns the
>   card facedown to the bottom of its deck.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect.  OP, please reconsider.

Comment: Hmm.  It seems you are correct about the face-down part after all.  My apologies - we have been playing it like Eldritch Horror for years (since before Eldritch Horror came out).  Your answer is still partially wrong then, though - you still can't run out of cards in a deck.  The deck will cycle without shuffling in that case.

Comment: You can run out of cards, with an extremely dedicated crew, by having someone (like Dexter Drake) get overzealous about spell collection, and hoard to the point of not using his spells fast enough to get them back in the deck.  This is why my answer also suggests that you should use spells in this situation,

Comment: Oh, I get it.  I misunderstood the entire point of this question.

Comment: No worries.  :)  As I read the question, it's basically "If the players currently have every spell card sitting in front of them, what happens if they would get more?", with my answer being "They get nothing -- so consider freely spending spell cards on such encounters so you get them back immediately!"